# Weird PHP FTP login issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect to a server setup using FTPES.  I looked online and I'm told the way to do this is using ftp_ssl_connect, so I have this code.  The variables are all defined to info I've been given.

```
$ftp = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server)  or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");

$login_result = ftp_login($ftp, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (!$login_result) {
    die("can't login");
}
```

It connects without issue but I get this output

**PHP Warning:  ftp_login(): Please specify the password. in /root/ftpes.php on line 10
can't login**

I have specified a password and this is were it gets a bit weird.  If I set the password to be incorrect, so change the last character, now I get the output

**PHP Warning:  ftp_login(): Login incorrect. in /root/ftpes.php on line 10**

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the server use 2-factor authentication?

Comment: I'm not in direct contact with the person who's server it is, I'm doing the work for a client.  I have got documentation though for connecting and using the server and there is no implication in there that there is an 2FA.  I am asking my client to contact the server owner to see if they have any ideas.

Comment: You should be able to tell by doing a manual FTP login.

Comment: This message seems to come from FogFTP when it's asking for the password. https://forums.fogproject.org/topic/4540/fogftp-login-failed/13 It doesn't mean the password was wrong, it's just part of the prompt. But maybe PHP doesn't parse it properly.